2006 iMac won't turn on - No Indicators of Life
I have an old iMac that ran like a beauty. It could play Minecraft like a champ, and was great for browsing and retro games. Recently, the iMac shut off and took a while to turn back on. It wouldn't show any signs of life until I swapped the outlet and it worked.
When I say shut it off, I mean black screen and completely powered off instantly.
Recently, it shut off again but now, a few days later I'm have no luck getting it to turn on. I've tried 3 cables and multiple outlets. It showed no signs of failure prior to shutting off randomly. Now when I plug it in and hold the power button, nothing happens. Not even the indication light. I've also tried reseating the RAM and swapping sticks entirely. I also tried unplugging it, holding the power button for about 30 seconds and waiting for a while before plugging it back in and trying again.
While this Mac is very old, it's my favorite piece of technology that I often use as a secondary device for fun. I'm not seeking closure, but that would still be nice if no troubleshooting steps work.

My guess is a power supply failure.
